# How to add custom parameters for Dialogs for QuickBlox iOS

Tags: ios, quickblox

With ref. http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Custom_parameters

i have created new class on http://admin.quickblox.com/ and named it as "qbCustomParam"

i have created QBChatDialog object

```
QBChatDialog *newDialog = [QBChatDialog new];
```

but couldn't find "data" property for QBChatDialog

but according to document they have mentioned :

```
newDialog.data = @{@"class_name": @"qbCustomParam", @"age": @33};
```

So where am i going wrong ?

Comment: Have you looked at QBChatDialog.h:50? @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *data;

Comment: there is no @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *data in QBChatDialog.h

Comment: Is your QBChatDialog.h looks like http://oi58.tinypic.com/2ninubn.jpg ?

Comment: i have downloaded Quickblox iOS SDK, version 2.2.3, there it has QBChatDialog.h:50? @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *data;

Comment: Give me the link to the page where you previously downloaded the SDK, I think there is a problem.

Comment: SDK that i downloaded previously was the latest that time, i think they have updated new SDK : http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#Download_iOS_SDK

Comment: Please ensure that you are using the latest SDK 2.2.3

Comment: @SML, have you solved this issue? If so then please answer your question so people like me would take benefit of it.

Comment: @hagile ,issue is resolved, i was using older SDK, use latest SDK.

Comment: @SML, thanks ! but now I don't remember why I've commented here.